# conversion of ajax(json) response to insert data in table with pure Java script (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to insert into an html table data, retrieved with ajax
the response arrive as:

```
[{"email":"marc@volvo.com","id":2,"name":"volvo"},{"email":"marc@mercedes.com","id":4,"name":"mercedes"}]
```

that's look fine, but when I try to access it as an object, I receive undefined.
if I bring it as json type, it show  the word object instead of the object content.
It should be an array of 2 object, with 3 value each, no matter what i tries i can't manage to access the value,
here's the javascript code (i don't know yet jquery) :

```
    function getCompanies(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CouponB/webapi/admin/company"
    req.open("GET", url, true)
    req.send()

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(req.readyState==4) {
            if(req.status==200){
                myStr = ""
                var resp = req.response
                alert(resp)
                myJson = eval(resp)
                alert(myJson)
                for(var x in myJson){
                    alert("-----------"+x.name)
                }
                var respTarg = document.getElementById("companyTable")
                resp.forEach(wtr)
                respTarg.innerHTML = myStr
            }

        }
    }
}

function wtd(d){
    return "<td style=\"width: 70px; \">"+d+"</td>"
}

function wtr(){
    myStr += wtd(this.id)+wtd(this.name)+wtd(this.email)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) to learn more about how to process nested data structures.

---

There are a couple of issue with your code:

- Using `eval` to parse the JSON (it works, but there is a better way)
- Using `for...in` to iterate over an array and incorrectly access array elements (`x` refers to the **index** of the element, not the element itself). (this is broken)
- Using `this` inside `wrt`. `forEach` *does* not make the current element available via `this`. (this is broken)
- Using a global variable `myStr` to build the HTML instead of having `wrt` return a string. (it works, but there is a better way)
- If `respTarg` is a `<table>` then you are forgetting to create rows (`<tr>`). (might work, but then all cells appear in a single row)

Having said that, here is a way to build a simple table:

```js
var resp = '[{"email":"marc@volvo.com","id":2,"name":"volvo"}, {"email":"marc@mercedes.com","id":4,"name":"mercedes"}]';

function insertCell(row, value) {
  // create a new cell in the provided row
  var cell = row.insertCell();
  // set the inline style of the cell
  cell.style = {width: '70px'};
  // set the content of the cell
  cell.textContent = value;
}

var table = document.getElementById('table');
// parse the JSON and for each object in the resulting array ...
JSON.parse(resp).forEach(function(obj) {
  // ... create a new row ...
  var row = table.insertRow();

  // ... and insert the following properties as cells into the row
  insertCell(row, obj.id);
  insertCell(row, obj.name);
  insertCell(row, obj.email);
});
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

---

Also, don't use `alert` for debugging, use `console.log` instead.